# Flow: Cannot call `this.state.gameBoard.map` because property `map` is missing in undefined

Tags: flowtype

```
type Color = "Blue" | "Red" | null

type Connect4Cell = {
    state: number,
    color: Color
}

type State = {
    gameBoard?: Array<Array<Connect4Cell>>
}

class Game extends React.Component<{||}, State> {

    state = {
        gameBoard: [
            [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], 
            [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], 
            [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], 
            [{state: 1, color: "Blue"}, {state: 1, color: "Red"}, {state: 1, color: "Blue"}, {state: 1, color: "Red"}, {state: 0, color: null}]
        ]
    }

    render() {

        let board = this.state.gameBoard.map<React.Element<any>>(row => <Row />)

        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <div>
                <p>This line comes from the render of class, Game. </p>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {board}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <Cell />
                <Row />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

I can't find out why its giving me this error?

Exact Error Message (on .map):

> Cannot call `this.state.gameBoard.map` because property `map` is
>   missing in  undefined [1].Flow(InferError)

Comment: By the way, not related to the direct question, but I think that this `this.state.gameBoard.map<React.Element<any>>(row => <Row />)` should be simply `this.state.gameBoard.map(row => <Row />)`

Answer (score 4):

The reason why there is in error is, that state is annotated as:

```js
type State = {
    gameBoard?: Array<Array<Connect4Cell>>
}
```

`?` sign is saying to flow that this value might be undefined.

As in the example, the initial state is set, and it contains `gameBoard` in needed shape, change that needs to be done is:

```js
type State = {
    gameBoard: Array<Array<Connect4Cell>>
}
```

However, if at any time of the component live it is expecting to have `gameBoard` not set, then the solution will be to add a check before calling `.map` function as following

```js
let board = this.state.gameBoard ? this.state.gameBoard.map(row => <Row />) : null;
```