# Why does flow complain if I put the checking into a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I wanna use a variable for the validation of an Array. So I did this:

```
const length = array ? array.length : 0;

if (length) {
   array.map(_ => _.displayName);
}
```

For this I get a flow error: `Cannot call 'array.map' because property`map`is missing in  undefined [1].Flow(InferError)`

Comment: Well, when you say `array ? array.length : 0;` that means you expect `array` might not exist. If it doesn't, then `array.map();` would throw an error. I suppose Flow doesn't actually take into account that if `array` doesn't exist you are also not going to run the `array.map()`.

Comment: Also note that though it's not the problem you're asking about, that call to `array.map()` won't really do anything because you're not saving the return value.

Comment: Can you edit the post to show how you are declaring the array?

Comment: If array is `[]` then `array === true` will be `true` not `false`. Just check for length in the `if` statement, `if(array.length) { ...}`

Comment: why is array.map not being assigned into a new variable?

Comment: @epascarello I assume for the sake of example. But yeah, probably worth bringing up.

Comment: So this is an error with Flow Type so I guess we should see how it is defined. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814940/flow-cannot-call-this-state-gameboard-map-because-property-map-is-missing-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do without knowing the type of `array`.

> Why does flow complain if I put the checking into a variable?

As a general rule, this doesn't work in flow. Refinement in flow is very limited. The [documentation on refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) basically lists every form of refinement that is supported, and checking `length` isn't one of them. You can't really do something like carry the fact that something is a certain type to a later point. Look, for example:

```
// Let's assume `array` is `Array<any> | null` for the sake of this example
const array: Array<any> | null = ([]: any);
```

We can refine `array` to an array by doing this:

```
if (Array.isArray(array)) {
  // here, _within this block,_ `array` is of type `Array<any>`
  (array: Array<any>);
}

// Here, `array` is `Array<any> | null` again
(array: Array<any>); // Error! Cannot cast `array` to array type 
  // because null [1] is incompatible with array type [2].
```

We could also do the opposite:

```
if (array === null) {
  // here, array is `null`
  (array: null);
} else {
  // and because this is in an `else` block, flow knows that
  // array is `Array<any>` here
  (array: Array<any>);
}

// ...and now it's back to `Array<any> | null` again:
(array: null); // Error! Cannot cast...
```

Because there are only two options in our union, a truthy one 
and a falsey one, we can just check the truthiness of `array`
to refine it:

```
if (array) {
  (array: Array<any>);
} else {
  (array: null);
}
```

So how about things we can't do?

Flow isn't smart enough to understand that `arrayIsArray`
carries information about refining `array`:

```
const arrayIsArray = Array.isArray(array);
if (arrayIsArray) {
  (array: Array<any>); // Error! Cannot cast...
}
```

As a general rule, refinements are scoped to the 
statement they occur in.

([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEBsFMBcHIGdQEN7wK4FtKgAZIE75ICeOoAlojgIKEkA8SAdsQHygA+oTa44ZAMwD2+UNAAW2eEgDW2IQLHjKoSAA8kGAA5QAUAGMhTeNGR1iALlC0ixRi3ZcefUAF5QACgDaAXSvNiAEoAbl1dEFAAd2x9ZlB8SAFyJmw8czJoIWQmM1tQACNiUAATIWSAcyVKC11yRQ8bEgA6SkbiDwJbQMDQAG9dUFAIyQSAGlAAfUjyCWSqxHzwIX0ZUYncTpIyFQUxYi1Utvs2HAHPTctrc2PWEN0AXzCIgAlIMY30iiojgMduXn4yHKSGSug65isPwcISGYAAooQRABCUAAYWYTCEpliJg+tgyWQuewOoDOEXykFiaHg2Gc4FAXgAjD4vhQmIZtEhoORFthphJciRidgvAAmHxNJ5gaKgQy8YrIcDwLKlJTyLRaITwGaQWr1ImuQ3-Pg9fqDYZvSDjIkqHB006DcG2Kx0u73VRK7Bm2HZBUUqk0+asuZxHCQT1kRbLVagARLSKgGSYyKICRcslgG3fa6-MgjXWOi6QnPQ0KPcJgJpV5gK5MUOALJArMRZGglticY2ApDA5I1J0kF0AmERBH4ZFojFY2UoaBVyUV0AAIUpSGp2AklrM8iY4CK0EiWSEWm5RkQcyEaFEaCY5CM1rE+DQEiKRmwi5ryFjSE9r5S4xlWIcgAK2pbFJGbTdH2fZQUlQUBdjSfFF0yeJEmSbAZhqOpznMU0zgHS4oTYN0PUDb1CKHE0yylUAAGUsnEIQEyQfJL1MWYmHKRBAOYWBTFKAB+WiADF4y+Jh+NAeAMAIUxIExNBynEFtQBvYo3hMT801MJCSAASXgNpTgiWJCHISBzyYYR8Fk08clY9i0KSW8uLxLZJUMYxTAuQy2jcK5bBaIzzEIu4cMIvy8L6Aii0ChhfhHeFEXwFF0SYTFsVnecHlo6hECQUBygUt4f3iXgrWcjCsCYaACoSaTDAOBVUKgxctOgSAao4yRX30fQrzZJogA))